# Make drag and drop uploader in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm  trying to make upload site that takes request and stores the files in 'static' folder in flask. I always get bad request when I try sending "POST" request on in.The only reason that I need it is to test my drag and drop javascript uploader. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['xhr2upload'] # [0]
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: You need to activate the debugger and find out what causes the 400 error. Post a traceback here if it doesn't make the cause obvious.

Comment: I set the debugger on, but still nothing. Only thing i get is Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: Does the debugger work at all (eg with other errors)? If not and you are running from the command line, you need to check that app.debug and app.propagate_exceptions are True.

Comment: The Debugger works but when i press upload it always just redirects my  and shows " Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Comment: There's no traceback on the console? What does the HTTP request look like in a debugger like Firebug or from the wire (with Wireshark)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a common problem to have with Flask early on - when you attempt to access [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.args), [`request.form`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.form), [`request.values`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.values) and [`request.files`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.files) they will throw a [`KeyError`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) if the key does not exist in them - just as an ordinary dictionary would in Python (try `{}["test"]` in any Python interpreter).  Flask adds a bit of sugar to the `request` dictionaries - its `KeyError` is actually a subclass of [`HTTPException`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest) that raises a 400 Bad Request if it is not caught. (See [this part of the quickstart documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object))

The line that is causing this issue is `request.files['xhr2upload']`.  You do not include any JavaScript on the page and the only `<input type="file">` you have on the page has the name of "file", not "xhr2upload".  Either change `request.files['xhr2upload']` to `request.files['file']` or load an ajax uploader into your page and have it post your files using the `xhr2upload` name.

If you have a form that *may* have a field and you want to check *if* a field is defined without raising a `KeyError` then you can use the `.get` method:

```
request.form["not_here"] # KeyError -> 400 Bad Request

request.form.get("might_be_here") # Value if provided, else None
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add "multiple" to file input tag, like so:

```html
<input type="file" name=file multiple>
```

and made an for bucle instead "file" on flask backend

```js
files = ...
for file in files
    file.save(os.path.join...
```